# OpenVZ can't create new Centos 7 container

Tags: centos-7, openvz

I have a brand new Centos 7.2 installation (required due to needing drivers for an Adaptec 6405 RAID controller), on which I'm trying to install OpenVZ.

The problem I have is that new container creation fails.  Here is the command I'm running, along with the output:

```
# prlctl create NewVM --vmtype ct --ostemplate centos-7-x86_64
Creating the Container...
Creating cache
Creating temporary Container
Creating virtual disk
Failed to register the CT: PRL_ERR_VZCTL_OPERATION_FAILED (Details: Creating OS template cache for centos-7-x86_64 template
Error: Failed to create ploop image /vz/tmp//vzpkg.2LV6kn/cache-private/root.hdd/root.hds: Error in ploop_umount (ploop.c:2488): Failed to find top delta name and format 2
Error: Cannot create ploop device
Error: Failed to read ploop disk descriptor /vz/tmp//vzpkg.2LV6kn/cache-private/root.hdd: Error in ploop_open_dd (di.c:363): Can't resolve /vz/tmp//vzpkg.2LV6kn/cache-private/root.hdd/DiskDescriptor.xml: No such file or directory 39
Creation of Container private area failed
)
Failed to create the virtual machine.
```

This happened before, and I thought that it was due to Centos 7 setting itself up to use xfs, so this machine was rebuilt using ext4 as the file system.

```
# df -TH
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3      ext4       53G  4.9G   46G  10% /
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.9G  9.7M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs          tmpfs     3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1      ext4      500M  245M  224M  53% /boot
/dev/sda2      ext4       87G   82M   82G   1% /home
tmpfs          tmpfs     778M  8.2k  778M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs          tmpfs     778M     0  778M   0% /run/user/1001
```

OpenVZ was installed using [these instructions](https://thegeeksalive.com/how-to-setup-openvz-7-on-centos-7/) as follows:

```
yum install https://download.openvz.org/virtuozzo/releases/openvz-7.0.3-479/x86_64/os/Packages/o/openvz-release-7.0.3-3.vz7.x86_64.rpm
yum install epel-release
yum install prlctl prl-disp-service vzkernel
reboot
```

Some more diagnostics:

```
# systemctl status vz
● vz.service - OpenVZ Container service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vz.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2018-01-11 16:55:10 AEDT; 25min ago
 Main PID: 697 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/vz.service

Jan 11 16:55:10 localhost systemd[1]: Starting OpenVZ Container service...
Jan 11 16:55:10 localhost vz[697]: net.ipv4.conf.venet0.send_redirects = 0
Jan 11 16:55:10 localhost vz[697]: net.ipv4.conf.venet0.rp_filter = 0
Jan 11 16:55:10 localhost vz[697]: 1     0.0.0.0                                  0.0.0.0
Jan 11 16:55:10 localhost vz[697]: 1     ::                                       00000000000000000000000000000000
Jan 11 16:55:10 localhost vz[697]: Classes loaded successfully.
Jan 11 16:55:10 localhost systemd[1]: Started OpenVZ Container service.
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try "strace": **strace -o NewVM.out** prlctl create NewVM --vmtype ct --ostemplate centos-7-x86_64
and then show your out file pls.: **less NewVM.out**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this was for a client and was time-sensitive, so we ended up installing VMWare instead.